Append number of elements belonging to the same group in each record in flink
While having a file which contains customer data in each line in comma separated format
customerId,Email

Same customer can have multiple emails, so there will be multiple lines for same customer with different email data as given below, Same customer data will be always be in sequential positions.
1234,1234a@email.com
1234,1234b@email.com
5678,5678a@email.com
9999,9999a@email.com
9999,9999b@email.com
9999,9999c@email.com

Need to read the file, and append the total number of emails for each customer in each line in downstream as given below
1234,1234a@email.com,2
1234,1234b@email.com,2
5678,5678a@email.com,1
9999,9999a@email.com,3
9999,9999b@email.com,3
9999,9999c@email.com,3

Which is a good approach to build this pipeline in flink. (Will be having millions of lines)

If you can't use the Table API for this, then I'd key by the customer id, and have a tumbling window with a very large size. Follow that with a .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction()), where you can iterate over every element to calculate the count before emitting results.
